# Android. There is only white screen on activity with InMobi ad

Tags: android

When i add InMobiAdView to my activity i see only white screen or empty space.
I tried to start demo app from manual. Result is the same.
Help please.

Comment: You really need to give more info, we can't help you at all like this. How about post some of your code, your android version, your sdk version, whether you are using a phone(and which one) or the emulator etc..

Comment: android 2.2. sdk a300. log cat : inmobi onAdRequestfailed error code NETWORK_ERROR. on emulator with android 2.1 problem is the same. it isn't my code, it is demo app.

Answer (score 1):

I work for InMobi.  Make sure that you're using the latest version and following an up-to-date tutorial.
All the latest code etc can be found in our Wiki http://developer.inmobi.com/wiki/

Comment: Does it always load the ad from the internet when it's called to be displayed? This results in just waiting for a little bit while the ad loads on slow connections.

Comment: I'm experiencing something similar with the web app integration. I will occasionally receive a white screen, without any error code.